# What IS about pictures or What ARE about pictures

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

When I want to ask about some subject in plural meaning which variant is right?

What IS about pictures or What ARE about pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example text in your thread title doesn't make sense, so it isn't answerable. Try a complete sentence, please.

Ok, Daniil, you've clarified in the comments that you started from the phrase "What about the pictures?" This is a valid expression in English, but it is technically a sentence fragment, and doesn't have a verb. You shouldn't insert either "is" or "are".
And what about the grammar? There's no problem with it!

Comment: Sentence: Ok, I understood your task. And what is about pictures? Should I find  them on the Internet?

Comment: Sorry, Daniil, "And what is about pictures?" doesn't make sense in English, so try explaining what your are asking instead of making a sentence.

Comment: My question means that I remind of the pictures and want to hear the explanations.
Google translates my phrase from russian as "what about the pictures". But I don't see the auxiliary.

Comment: Thanks very much!